# Can you reuse the alias of a derived table inside the query that makes up the derived table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have seen a few queries where the alias of the derived table is also used in the query that makes up the derived table.  Can anyone confirm if this is allowable or not?

Here is a sample query.  Pay attention to how alias "st" is used twice:

```
SELECT ft.ThisColumn, st.OtherID
FROM FirstTable ft
INNER JOIN
(SELECT st.CommonID,st.OtherID,DateEntered,DateExited,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY OtherID ORDER BY DateEntered DESC) stRank
             FROM SecondTable st
             WHERE (@StartDate BETWEEN DateEntered and DateExited)
) st
ON ft.CommonID=st.CommonID AND st.stRank=1
```

Is it OK to use the same alias "st" in these two different places?

Comment: Yes, that's allowed.  They are both used in 2 different scopes that don't conflict with each other.

Comment: **sstan** - thanks for the confirmation

Comment: **Martin Smith** - I know it executes - I just wanted to know if this was somehow not a mistake (e.g. a bug in SQL Server that allows this to execute when it should not).  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *st* inside the derived table is only accessible inside that query and only inside phases that will be executed after FROM clause, and that is OK as it is not accessible in outside context.

The second *st* is an alias for the whole derived table's results which will be used in the outer context and inside phases that will be executed after FROM clause and that is OK too.

As you know, first the FROM of outer query clause will be executed and that will cause the derived table to be executed and after that the result(which are relational) returned by the derived table will get *st* as alias and will be participated in your join query.

**Additional Note:** Please keep in mind that Sql Server databases has a close relation with mathematical relations and sets, and as you know all the sets in mathematical theories should have a valid name as we need to refer to them, so every relation in sql server(Table, View, Table Expression such as derived table or CTE and etc) should have a valid name too.

But I advice you not to use two aliases with same name in one query, even if their logical processing phase is different, because it will reduce the readability of your query.

In short, your query is correct and valid.

Comment: **Vahid Farahmandian** - thanks for detailed explanation - helps a lot